# The right way to resolve a bug in an open source project, issue or pull request?

Tags: git, github

There is an open source project on Github and I found a small bug in that and resolved it with a small and simple change.

The project does not have a CONTRIBUTING file.

What is the best way to contribute to this project? should I make a pull request with my bug-free code or should I create an issue, explaining the problem and propose my solution?

Comment: Why not both? Then in the pull-request you can reference (and close) the issue.

Comment: There is no general rule. Most of the times, we open an issue to describe the bug and after every one is able to do the development and create a PR. But if you already did the development, create the PR and you will see what the maintainer will told you.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the project and the type of change you want to make.

If a change is straightforward and obviously correct (e.g., there was an obvious bug where it was broken before, and with this change it no longer is), then it's often fine just to open a pull request.

If there's a situation where the proposed change is larger (e.g., adding a new feature or API), where the maintainer is going to want to have input (e.g., updating project contribution documentation), or where the issue is more nebulous, then it's best to open an issue first. The maintainer may be able to provide you with direction or alternatives that you hadn't considered, and will likely appreciate that you considered their input before charging forward.

Of course, if the project documentation says differently, then do that.

In this case, since you're adding project-relevant documentation, an issue is probably appropriate. Perhaps they will have things they want in their contributing documentation, like an email address for security issues or a code of conduct they'd like to use, and you can seek their input and then write up a PR fixing the issue.